# expected unqualified-id error on creating a library in Arduino

Tags: arduino

I am trying to create my own library on Arduino while also using a different library. But I get this error in line 12 of my header file:

> expected unqualified-id before ')' token

Main file:

```
#include "firealarm.h" 
void setup() {
  firealarm.begin;
}

void loop() {
  firealarm.gas_values();
}
```

The header file:

```
#include <MQ2.h>

#ifndef firealarm
#define firealarm

#if ARDUINO >= 100
#include "Arduino.h"
#endif

class firealarm {
  public:
    firealarm(); //this is where it says the error occurs
    void begin (int baudRate = 9600);
    gas_values()
  private:
    MQ2 mq2(A0);

    int lpg, co, smoke;

};
#endif
```

The Cpp file:

```
#include "firealarm.h"

firealarm::firealarm() :
{
}
void firealarm::begin(int baudrate)
{
    Serial.begin(baudrate);
    Serial.println("Firealarm libary created successfully")
        mq2.begin;
}
void firealarm::gas_values()
{
    float *values = mq2.read(true);
    lpg = mq2.readLPG();
    co = mq2.readCO();
    smoke = mq2.readSmoke();
}
```

I am also planning to include a different library in this. But I could not manage to get it working with just one.

Comment: You should include the exact error message - what line does the error refer to?

Comment: sorry about that, I thought adding comments next to where the error occured is suffiecient.

Comment: sorry about that, I thought adding comments next to where the error occured is suffiecient.

Answer (score 0):

Among other issues, you `#define firealarm` near the top of `firealarm.h`, which means that any time the word `firealarm` appears later in the file, it will be removed entirely. So to the compiler, your file looks like this:

```
class  {
    public:
        ();
// ..... more code
```

This is not valid C++, and so the compiler throws an error. You have more errors later in the file, such as the declaration of the function `gas_values` which does not have a return type, and does not have a semicolon at the end of the line.

Rename your include guard (the `#ifdef` and `#define` lines) to a word that you do not use, like `__firealarm_h_included`, or replace them (and the `#endif` line) with a single `#pragma once`

Comment: Hi, yeah you are right. My initial error is now cleared up, but other has popped out.I will try to sort them out first